# This recipe requires a large number/quantity of eggs and a generous amount of butter

Tags: word-choice

Which is more appropriate? number or quantity?

> This recipe requires a large **number/quantity** of eggs and a generous amount of butter.

I'm a bit inclined to use **quantity** because it gels well with "a generous amount of butter".

> a large **quantity** of eggs and a **generous** amount of butter.

Comment: You could go with "A large number of eggs and a generous quantity of butter". :D English is really flexible, so do whichever of them you prefer.

Comment: Well, you couldn't say " a generous number of butter". :P

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I prefer "number" because eggs are countable (not "[count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_noun)").

Quantity *can* refer to numbers as well but they can also refer to volumes and weights.

Technically both are acceptable and will be understood.

Comment: +1 Me, if I'm being that vague I'll just say "This recipe takes a lot of eggs and butter".

Comment: I'm a bit inclined to use quantity because it gels well with "a generous amount of butter".